# How to make the application unfocusable, when some function is running?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a button in my application. When I clicked the button I am starting some function using thread. When the thread is running I don't want any of my view get focus (including tab also). How can I make the whole application unfocusable/untouchable till the thread completes its working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should show a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog). If you don't do so, the user will think that your app is frozen. You can use the `setCancelabel(false)` method in order to prevent user from closing the dialog.

Comment: I am using a progressbar when the thread starts and stop this progress bar when the thread completes. But still other buttons are touchable. Can we do anything with progressbar for making the views unfocusable? Or it is possible only with progressdialog?

Comment: Well... you can do it... but I don't recommend it. What you can do is creating a transparent overlay view, and put it above the content of your activity (it will gain the focus, and won't allow the user to interact with the app). Also, override the `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` to prevent user from pressing the back key.  Once again: try to avoid such techniques.